# Need site inventory tool for SharePoint 2007 that doesn't require server access

Tags: 2007, powershell, migration, sharepoint-server, auditing

We're migrating from 2007 to 2010 and I need a full inventory (site, libraries, lists) so I can remove stuff that's no longer being used. However, everything I've found so far requires server access. I'm only concerned with one department (e.g. example.com/departments/marketing) - I don't have access to the higher level directories.

I am a site owner who has full control over the sites in /marketing, but I can't install anything on the server. Any ideas? TIA.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the built in Content and Structure functionality? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx

You find it by:

1. Click Site Actions, and then click Mange Content and Structure.
2. If Manage Content and Structure is not listed, perform the following steps:

   1. Point to Site Settings, click Modify All Site Settings, and then under Site Collection Administration, click Go to top level site settings.
   2. Under Site Administration, click Content and Structure.